# MayaCharm: connection to maya refused

Tags: pycharm, maya

I recently installed PyCharm and MayaCharm to use with Maya. It worked fine the first time, but now when I try to use it I only get the error message that *MayaCharm: Connection to Maya refused* and I was wondering what to do? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this in Maya before starting to run script in PyCharm:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
if not cmds.commandPort(':4434', q=True):
   cmds.commandPort(n=':4434')
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I did try this beforehand, but it did not work. Ended up just programming in Maya's script editor.